# Not getting a response from web-api with javascript (without JS-Framework)

Tags: javascript, api

I want to get the response from the URI: 
http://filzmelodie.norhabo.com/chat/api/SalesOnlineStatus

This API will return a string "0" or "1".
How can I get the response in Javascript?

This is my code:

```
function getSosFromNorHaBo() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', "http://filzmelodie.norhabo.com/chat/api/SalesOnlineStatus");
    script.onreadystatechange = setSosToHuaXing( /*How could I get the response of API?*/ );
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function setSosToHuaXing(data){
    alert(data);
}
setInterval(function(){getSosFromNorHaBo()}, 1000 * 1);
```

How could I get the response of API? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get response from server with Javascript after Javascript request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193976/get-response-from-server-with-javascript-after-javascript-request)

Comment: @ManikArora When I use this method, I got this Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://filzmelodie.norhabo.com/chat/api/SalesOnlineStatus. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you making the Cross-Origin request? The error you see occurs when the server doesn't serves Cross-Origin requests. I am adding a code as the answer below try to test it out, it may work but I am not sure, as I don't know how the API have been configured on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Function to create cross origin request-

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        // XHR has 'withCredentials' property only if it supports CORS
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){ // if IE use XDR
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Use the function-

```
function getSosFromNorHaBo() {
    var request = createCORSRequest( "get", "http://filzmelodie.norhabo.com/chat/api/SalesOnlineStatus" );
        if ( request ){
            // Define a callback function
            request.onload = setSosToHuaXing;
            // Send request
            request.send();
        }
    }

function setSosToHuaXing(data){
    alert(data);
}
setInterval(function(){getSosFromNorHaBo()}, 1000 * 1);
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://filzmelodie.norhabo.com/chat/api/SalesOnlineStatus. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: When ever a request is sent to the server, the requesting domain name is also sent and server checks whether it should send the response or not. If the server is configured to allow CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing, then only it would send the response and along with it the response header - Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *

Comment: You are right! This API has no Header Acc Control Allow Origin.  I will close this question. Thank you very much!